# How can I target and disable the nth LI in a UL list?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I need your help,

How would I go about targeting and applying a disabled prop on the Nth LI in a UL list using jQuery?

For example, if I were to select the 3rd LI in my UL and apply a disabled prop to it:

```
<div id="menu1">
    <ul>

        <li>Apples</li>
        <li>Oranges</li>
        <li disabled>Pears</li>
        <li>Bananas</li>        
    </ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To change the `disabled` property you should use the [`.prop()`](http://api.jquery.com/prop) function.

Try this:

```
$('li:eq(2)').prop('disabled', true);
```

Index for [`eq()`](http://api.jquery.com/eq-selector/) begins at 0, so `eq(2)` would get the 3rd `li`

Answer (score 2):

you could use [:eq()](http://api.jquery.com/eq-selector/) selector, as:

```
$( "ul li:eq( 2 )" ).attr( "disabled", "disabled" );
```

index is Zero-based, so 2 would select third `li`

Answer (score 1):

```
$("ul li").eq(2).attr("disabled","")
```

Answer (score 1):

`$('li:nt-child(3)')` will select what you want in this case.

Be aware this particular case will select all 3rd `li` items, not just the ones in your div.

Comment: Make use of the menu1 id `$('#menu1 li:nt-child(3)')`